# How to handle error in 'get' request in runtime?

Tags: angularjs, error-handling, get

I am using $http service in AngularJS to make a get request to a url

```
$http.get(url).
    success(function(data){
     ... // store data in localStorage
    }).
    error(function(){
     ... // get data from localStorage
    });
```

When the server is down the 'error' condition above gets executed but the application halts. I want the application to continue processing. So in the case of error the application should get data from localStorage.

I tried exception handling with try and catch but the application still halts.

```
try{
    $http.get(url).
    ... // store data in localStorage
 }
 catch(ex){
  ...  // get data from localStorage
 }
```

The reason for trying try catch is that in a simple try catch block it is possible to continue execution even if there is an exception being thrown.

I would like to know how solve this problem.

Comment: I think that you should to make it on your backend.

Comment: If its an http error you are getting, then the application should not halt. Can you specify the exception you are getting?

Comment: @user1537766 Not a http error. I get "GET <url> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Answer (score 0):

$http.get(url).
    success(function(data){
     ... // store data in localStorage
    }).
    error(function(){ 
    if (error.status == 500 || error.status == 406) {
      // get data from localStorage
    }
   }
 });